# Распознание английских названий чисел

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь решить такую вот простенькую задачу:
Написать программу для распознания английских названий чисел. Примеры ввода 
и вывода: «six» — 6. Числа от -20 до 20.
Но не выходит. Выдает завершение работы программы. Подскажите, что не так.

```
vector <int> ch=     {-20,-19,-17,-16,-15,-14,-13,-12,-11,-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
vector <string> sl={"minus twenty","minus nineteen","minus eighteen","minus seventeen","minus sixteen","minus fiveteen","minus fourteen","minus thirdteen", "minus twelve","minus eleven", "minus ten","minus nine","minus eight","minus seven", "minus six","minus five","minus four"," minus three", "minus two", "minus one", "zero", "one","two","three","four","five","six","seven" ,"eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve","thirdteen","fourteen","fiveteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen","twenty"};

int main(){
cout << "Vvedite chislo" <<endl;

 for( int i: ch){
while(cin>> sl[i]){
    sl[i]=ch[i];
cout << "Sootvetstvie s:" <<sl[i] <<endl;
}

 }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @boris887, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: while(cin>> sl[i])`.

Вы уверены?

    sl[i]=ch[i]

Это вообще компилируется?

Comment: Вроде как да, ну я просто пробовал различные варианты, надеясь на удачу :)   Так как, собственно, правильно?

Comment: Продолжайте дальше "на удачу" перебирать операторы и конструкции. Может быть, докажете теорему о том, что тысячи обезьян, просто тыкая по клавиатуре, могут набрать "Войну и мир".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Из cin Вам нужно сохранять введенное в отдельную переменную, а затем, используя, например, функцию find, find_if или операторы '[]' и '=', в Вашем векторе со словами найти введенное слово. В случае успеха, вывести соответствующее найденному слову число.

Учитывая элементарность задачи, Вам следует проделать все это самому.
А когда получится, попробуйте заменить два вектора на map<string, int>, и переделайте логику соответственно :)

На всякий случай добавлю, что вылетает Ваша программа при первом обращении к индексу вектора с номером i, поскольку первое значение i будет -20, а такого элемента быть не может. Перебор надо делать с 0 до размера массива, если по индексам. 
И строчка, где Вы присваиваете i-му элементу массива строк (т.е. строке) значение i-го элемента массива чисел (т.е. число), не должна компилироваться, потому что эта строчка не имеет смысла.

Comment: Благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

`cin >> s` читает до ближайшего пробела. Чтобы прочитать всю строчку, можно использовать `std::getline()`.

Вмеcто двух vector<> можно использовать map<>, как предложил [@smallFish](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/360060/):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  const unordered_map<string, int> numbers = {
    {"minus twenty", -20},
    {"minus nineteen", -19},
    // ...
    {"nineteen", 19},
    {"twenty", 20}
  };
  for (string line; getline(cin, line); ) { // one number per line
    auto p = numbers.find(line);
    if (p != numbers.end())
      cout << p->second << "\n";
    else
      cerr << "error: can't convert '" << line << "' to an integer" << endl;
  }
}
```

Пример:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 *.cpp && echo -e "minus twenty\nnineteen" | ./a.out
-20
19
```